# Mysql - Group by month with Y-m-d format

Tags: mysql

If I have column 'date' in format 'Y-m-d', can I use GROUP BY based on date column but group by months?

Answer (score 30):

Use MySQL's [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to group only on the desired parts:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(my_column, '%Y-%m')
```

Answer (score 8):

For Example: `created_at` is the column you need

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Note that you will need to select `created_at`.